# Laravel: Why am I getting a 401 response from Passport in my feature test?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-7

I am unsuccessfully trying to test authentication using [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport).

Here is my feature test:

```
public function a_user_can_authenticate_using_email() { 

    // Install passport.
    $this->artisan('passport:install', ['--no-interaction' => true]);

    // Create a user.
    $user = factory(User::class)->create([
        'username' => 'test@example.com',
        'password' => 'password',
    ]);

    // Get the id & secret.
    $client = DB::table('oauth_clients')
            ->where('password_client', true)
            ->first();

    // dd('id: ' . $client->id);  // works great
    // dd('secret: ' . $client->secret); // works great
    // dd('username: ' . $credentials['username']); // works great
    // dd('password: ' . $credentials['password']); // works great

    $response = Http::asForm()->post(env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/token', [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => $client->id,
        'client_secret' => $client->secret,
        'username' => $credentials['username'],
        'password' => $credentials['password'],
        'scope' => '*',
    ]);

    dd($response->status()); // 401
}
```

If I dump the response body, I am seeing an invalid client:

```
dd($response->body()); 

"{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed","message":"Client authentication failed"}"
```

I don't understand why I am seeing this error in my test.
If I use Postman to test my application, everything works great so I'm confident this is something specific to my test.

I am using `sqlite` memory database.

If I hardcode these values in my `.env` or just right in the test block, everything works great as well. How can I properly get the values from the database in my test? Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Did you add the class on middleware?

Comment: `The latest OAuth 2.0 Security Best Current Practice disallows the password grant entirely.` https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/archy-bold/bd696e8ec84a7657b724523e07fd7a6c) might help you.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to run `$user->save()` so the user is saved to the database before using it to log in.